# Swift 2.1 opposite of removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Because I do not want topContainer to show till later. I removed it from the superview on `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//somecode
    topContainer.removeFromSuperview()
//somecode
}
```

What is the function to restore it?

I tried `insertSubview` but don’t know if this is the correct way and if so, how do I get the subview index for this func second param? I could not find it looking for it in the right panel.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //...
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> //...
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        //<------------ I need to show it again here
    default:
        break
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use addSubview to append a view.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: To clear out, you are creating topContainer (which is a view that has other views right?) via storyboard or xib and then removing it from the view? And now you want to add it back

Comment: topContainer via storyboard which segue to tableView controller. Yes that is correct. I want it to disappear and reappear later.

Comment: as @Alex pointed out, use self.view.addSubview(). I would personally drop a little animation.

Comment: self.view.addSubview(topContainer) does not show topContainer up. I edited the question to clear my intension at the start of the code.

Comment: Are you setting auto layout constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes. auto layout are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a view to "show until later" then all you need to do is set its `hidden` to `true`. That way it doesn't lose its place in the hierarchy of views and it doesn't get deleted.

When you want the view to show, `myView.hidden = false`.

Comment: false is not a valid value. do you mean GL_FALSE

Comment: `false` *is* a valid value in Swift.

Comment: attributeInspector > Drawing > Hidden is checked. now in the code topContainer.hidden = false, red line says (cannot assign value of type CFBoolean to Bool)

Comment: its totally fine for `myView.hidden = false`, something wrong with your code apparently

Comment: but it still takes up the space which I don't want and setting a height constraint doesn't help either